# Unrecognized selector sent to class singleton arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, automatic-ref-counting, unrecognized-selector

I have a singleton class setup in the following way

My .h has the following code

```
 + (Singleton *)sharedInstance;
```

.m looks like the following

```
+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance
{
        if (nil == sharedInstance) {
           sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

When i try to access a method in the Singleton class from another class i get the following error

```
  reason: '+[Singeleton myMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to class
```

myMethod exists in my Singleton Class.

The Single Class uses ARC while the calling class is Non-ARC.

I am not sure if that has do anything with this.

myMethod is a NSNotification and i am calling that method by send it a dictionary object and using the notification name.

Edit: I did try reading and implementing suggestions on other threads that didn't seem to help.

Comment: could u plz share ur Singleton implementation?

Comment: myMethod contains any params ?

Comment: there is nothing with arc. How did you called the `myMethod` ?

Comment: i have updated the main thread

Comment: Please check my answer and let us know if that applies. If not, please include the definition of `myMethod:` as well as the call to `myMethod:`.

Comment: `Singleton *yourTone = [Singleton shareInstance]; [yourTone yourMethod];`

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have invoked a class method instead of an instance method.

So you most likely did:

```
[Singleton myMethod:...];
```

Correct your call to:

```
[[Singleton sharedInstance] myMethod:...];
```

Edit:

Ow, I now realized an even worse issue; your singleton factory is broken. There is no instance you are returning. Try this variant. It is not thread safe but may be good enough for you.

```
+ (Singleton*)sharedInstance 
{
    static Singleton *instance = nil;
    if (nil == instance) 
    {
        instance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
    }
    return instance;
}
```